# Save last updated ID and date from history update made during update change trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a `drivers` table which has the following fields:

```
driver_id
first_name
last_name
nationality
dob
last_update_id
last_update_datetime
```

I would like to save the old data to a `drivers_history` table which is pretty much a mirror copy of that table and then return the id of that row and the `datetime` back to the `drivers` table in the `last_update_id` and `last_update_datetime` fields whenever an update has been made to the data.

I have the following code so far for the trigger but my knowledge of MySQL is limited coming from an ASP.Net/SQL Server background.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS history_trigger $$

CREATE TRIGGER drivers_history_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON drivers
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT;
    IF OLD.first_name != NEW.first_name THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.last_name != NEW.last_name THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.nationality != NEW.nationality THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.dob != NEW.dob THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;

    IF _count > 0
    THEN
      INSERT INTO drivers_history (
        first_name,
        last_name,
        nationality,
        dob,
        last_update_id,
        last_update_datetime
      ) 
      VALUES (
        NEW.first_name,
        NEW.last_name,
        NEW.nationality,
        NEW.dob,
        NULL,
        NULL
      );
    END IF;
  END;
$$
```

I don't know if this code works but it is where I am at so far. Please can somebody help me fill in the rest of it?

**First rehash of attempted trigger code**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS history_trigger $$

CREATE TRIGGER drivers_history_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON drivers
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF OLD.first_name != NEW.first_name THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.last_name != NEW.last_name THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.nationality != NEW.nationality THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;
    IF OLD.dob != NEW.dob THEN _count = _count + 1 END IF;

    IF _count > 0
    THEN
      INSERT INTO drivers_history (
        first_name,
        last_name,
        nationality,
        dob,
        last_update_id,
        last_update_datetime
      ) 
      VALUES (
        OLD.first_name,
        OLD.last_name,
        OLD.nationality,
        OLD.dob,
        OLD.last_update_id,
        OLD.last_update_datetime
      );
    END IF;
  END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

```
DECLARE _count INT;
```

must be `declare _count INT DEFAULT 0`, according to [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html), not specifying a `default` value means variable value is `NULL` and `NULL` + `something_numeric` is `NULL`.

If you say you want to save old data, your insert statement must be rewritten as:

```
INSERT INTO drivers_history (
        first_name,
        last_name,
        nationality,
        dob,
        last_update_id,
        last_update_datetime
      ) 
      VALUES (
        old.first_name,
        old.last_name,
        old.nationality,
        old.dob,
        NULL,
        NULL
      );
```

I would like you to clarify what does `last_update_id` mean? I guess `last_update_datetime` is of type `TIMESTAMP` and will be updated automatically if you have specified in the creation table statement for that table. Also providing `NULL` for the values of the last two fields will prevent you to retrieve correctly, because you would be getting `NULL` for both values once you query back drivers_history, so to me doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. last_update_id and last_update_datetime would be NULL for a new entry and then it would point to the previous history record if a change has been made. I would like to save the record in the history table and then pass the id and datetime back to the drivers table.

Comment: I want to add that they are null at the minute because I don't know what to put there.